# How to set pixel color properly in glsl fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, colors, glsl, shader

```
uniform sampler2D textureY;
        uniform sampler2D textureUV;
        uniform int rect_width;
        layout(origin_upper_left) in vec4 gl_FragCoord;
        void main(void)
        {
        vec3 yuv; 
        vec3 rgb; 
        yuv.x = texture2D(textureY, textureOut.st).r - 0.0625; 
        yuv.y = texture2D(textureUV, textureOut.st).r - 0.5; 
        yuv.z = texture2D(textureUV, textureOut.st).g - 0.5; 
        rgb = mat3( 1,       1,         1, 
                    0,       -0.39465,  2.03211, 
                    1.13983, -0.58060,  0) * yuv; 
        gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, 1);  //This Works, output is correct texture
  
  vec3 green = vec3(0, 255, 0); 
  //vec3 green = vec3(0, 0.5, 0); //doesnt help too
  //vec3 green = vec3(0, 100.5, 0); //doesnt help too
  //vec3 green = vec3(0, 100.5f, 0); //write warning, doesnt help too
         int width = rect_width; 
        gl_FragColor = (green, 1);//whole sceen became white  
  if(TL;DR) gl_FragColor = (green, 1); //Creates desired rectangle but white color not green        
  }
```

OpenGL 3.3, with Qt if it is matter. I cant draw texture normally, but when i change color of fragment explicitely, it always became white, no matter which params i use. I tried "vec3 green = vec3(0, 0.5, 0); gl_FragColor = (green, 1);" "vec3 green = vec3(0, 255, 0); gl_FragColor = (green, 1);" and other variants, they just don't working. I even can output unfilled rectangle, but only white.

Answer (score 2):

`gl_FragColor` is a `vec4`. You should explicitly define its type. Also, those colors are normalized, that means they are in a range from `0.0f` to `1.0f`.

This should work:

```
vec3 green = vec3(0, 1.0f, 0);
gl_FragColor = vec4(green, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something something *comma operator* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). The expression `(green, 1)` evaluates to just `1`. So your code is effectively `gl_FragColor = 1;`. If you want a vector type expression, you must specify the vector type.

Answer (score 1):

**From your code:**

```
gl_FragColor = (green, 1);//whole sceen became white
```

That assignment uses the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) which makes the expression return 1. So you are essentially assigning 1 to gl_FragColor

According to the specifications of [GLSL 150](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.50.pdf) which is for OpenGL 3.2

```
out vec4  gl_FragColor;                    // deprecated
```

In the list of allowed [implicit conversions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.50.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A97%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C115.2%2C684%2C0%5D) your int (1) to vec4 is not there.

So we need to sort out that issue first,
example solution:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(green.rgb, 1.0);
```

The next problem is the values of green. OpenGL expects gl_FragColor to contain normalized color values. ( I couldn't easily find an obvious source that states this )

Changing green to satisfy these requirements would result in something like this:

```
vec3 green = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
gl_FragColor = vec4(green.rgb, 1.0);
```

**Note:** Be wary of the types when assigning values. Some graphics drivers lets you assign eg: 1 or vec3 to gl_FragColor while others adhere more closely to the spefications and will just return an error while compiling the shader. You can find the list of allowed implicit conversions earlier in my post.